# MySQL order of deletion in related databases?

Tags: mysql, relationship

I am trying to figure out how to delete something if and only if it does its relations are non existent?

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to delete something "if and only if its relations are non-existent". @Desolator's answer deletes regardless, and the relations too. What you actually asked for is given by RESTRICT rather than CASCADE.